# How do I know my ImageDataGenerator is working?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I am trying to use an *ImageDataGenerator* to artificially increase my total training images. My images are about 200,000 and the total number of images used per epoch when using *model.fit_generator* is about 5000+ which is the same number when I am using *model.fit*. Can I see the total number of images "generated"?. How do I know if the ImageDataGenerator is working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can plot some image of the data generator:

```py
#catch a few image of train_generator.
x_batch, y_batch = next(train_generator)

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 9))
for k, (img, lbl) in enumerate(zip(x_batch, y_batch)):
    plt.subplot(4, 8, k+1)#4 rows with 8 images.
    plt.imshow((img + 1) / 2)
    plt.axis('off')
```

The number of samples is the next code:

```py
print (train_generator.samples)
```